# Graph of Pulses in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I do this figure with `tikz`? [image]

Comment: this is one example of a question the community dislikes very much. please provide a minimal working example, which shows some amount of effort you put in any kind of solution you tried to come up with yourself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. This looks a bit like the first example from [TeXample: More tikz-timing examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/more-tikz-timing-examples/) (the one with the S, R, and Q signals). If you have nothing written yet, start there. If you have something written, please show us.

Answer (score 1):

- Load the TikZ package:

  ```
  \usepackage{tikz}
  ```
- Use the `tikzpicture` environment:

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```
- use the `\draw` command to draw lines, such as `\draw (coordinate1) -- (coordinate2);`
- use `|-` or `-|` for orthogonal paths
- use options for `\draw`, such as `[dashed]`, `[dotted]`, `[thick]` for the appearance of lines
- use the TikZ manual for a tutorial and a reference: http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz
- use TeX.SE if you got a *concrete specific question* how something specific works or if you got a problem in drawing

Comment: I think Martin's tikz-timing is the deal here